# How can I access the elements of a pointer-to-map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I've passed a map by pointer to a function, but now I'm unable to change the contents of the map because the code doesn't compile. I'm unsure whether I'm even allowed to pass the map as a pointer. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void faa(map<int,string> *baa){
   *baa[1] = "somethingnew";
}

int main(){
    map<int,string> bar;
    bar[1] = "one";
    bar[2] = "two";
    bar[3] = "three";

    int ii;
    for(ii=1;ii<4;ii++){
        cout<<"bar["<<ii<<"]="<<bar[ii]<<endl;
    }

    faa(&bar);
    cout<<"after"<<endl;
    for(ii=1;ii<4;ii++){
        cout<<"bar["<<ii<<"]="<<bar[ii]<<endl;
    }
}
```

When I compile this I get the error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::map >’)
     *baa[1] = "somethingnew";
```

Is a function like faa possible? What is the syntax?

Comment: `(*baa)[1]` should work instead

Comment: @ddriver doesn't have the same meaning WRT `const`ness and what to do with unfound keys though.

Comment: @ddriver `at` and `operator[]` are semantically different if the key is not found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to operator precedence rules, `*baa[1]` is parsed as `*(baa[1])` instead of `(*baa)[1]`. You could just put in the parentheses to make it work. However, you'd be better off using references instead:

```
void faa(map<int,string> &baa){
   baa[1] = "somethingnew";
}
```

Then you just call the function without taking the address of the map:

```
faa(bar);
```

Comment: Plus1 for pointing out use of reference. That is the way to go with STL containers in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(*baa)[1]` instead.

The default precedence is the same as if you wrote `*(baa[1])`

To explain the error message: if `baa` is a pointer, you can use the `[]` operator to access the nth element pointed by the pointer, therefore the type of `baa[1]` is an `std::map`, and it has no * operator.